# wix: can not see in add remove program after installing msi

Tags: silent-installer

IN wix project, i do not use ARPNOREMOVE property to forbid product from adding the interface to add/remove programs, but i cannot see in add remove programs.
 any one who can give me some suggestions? any suggestions i will appreciate.
My Product.wxs like below

```
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
<Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="1"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you add some more context to your question? Which technology are you working in? Is that wix? You can add the technology / language / framework to the tags to get answers sooner.